# Need to group shows by day in a rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get shows on a certain day to show up just for that day and I would like to be able to see what shows are going on in the next couple of days as well.

The View:

```
<% t = Time.new %>
<h2 class="center" style="color:#2A2C2B"><u><%= t.strftime("%A, %B %e") %></u></h2>

<% @clubs.each do |club| %>
  <!-- # <%  club.shows.future.present? %> -->
  <h1 class="club"><%= link_to club.name, club.website %> </h1>

  <% club.shows.future.each do |show| %>
    <h3 class="center"><%= show.pretty_start_time %></h3>
    <% show.comedians.each do |comedian| %>
      <div>
        <ol>
          <h4 class="comedian"><%= link_to simple_format(comedian.name),comedian_path(comedian) %></h4>
          <p class="bio"><u><%= comedian.bio %></u></p>
        </ol>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%- end -%>
```

The Comedy Hub Controller:

```
class ComedyHubsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @clubs = ComedyClub.all
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to show your model code. Which column on show is a DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<% shows.goup_by{|show| show.date}.each do |dategroup| %>
    <# do something to indicated the group up here? %>
    <%= dategroup.each do |show| %>
        <li> <%# put details here %> </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there is a DateTime column on Show called `start` and the ComedyClub model has a a `has_many :shows` and the Show model has the `belongs_to :comedy_club` association defined

In your ComedayHubsController#show method, do the following query

```
@clubs = ComedyClub.join(:shows).where("shows.start >=?", DateTime.now).order("shows.start ASC")
```

Now only clubs with shows in the future will be sent to the view and already ordered by start.